# FB.UIServer.setLoadedNode is undefined - SDK change?

Tags: facebook

I've been using the FB.UIServer.setLoadedNode method to resolve issues in IE9 for awhile now.

Without changing anything on our production servers, this is now throwing the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'setLoadedNode' of undefined
```

Did something change with the SDK? Is this a bug that FB finally fixed?

Comment: You are talking about the JS SDK? You’re not supposed to use any methods thereof that are not in the official documentation. Everything not in there might change at any time without notice.

Comment: huh, well I threw a if(FB.UIServer) { // code } wrapper around this line so other browsers would work. For grins I tested it in IE9 and it seems to be working.